# this error is stress me please solve it for me 'Uncaught TypeError: e.target.className.add is not a function'

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i have this problem again and again and i don't know what's the problem

```
document.addEventListener("click" , (e)=>{
  if (e.target.className === 'letter-box') {
    e.target.className.add("clicked")
  }
})
```

handle clicking on letters

Comment: className property is a string, thus it does not have a method "add". A quick way to add text to it is by using className += " text" (note the initial space). I suggest you to rely on support libraries (eg. JQuery) to handle classes properly

Comment: What is unclear about this error message? Have you done any debugging? `console.log(e.target.className.add);` and `console.log(e.target.className);` would’ve made it immediately obvious what the problem is. Strings don’t have an `add` method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use element.classList.add() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
it will not remove existing classes assigned to the element